# iOS Tableview scroll lagging if location services are ON

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, location

I have an application where I am getting the location of the device using an instance of CLLocationManager.

Now when I am calling a function which is using `self.locationManager.location` to get the location **inside every cell** of the tableview. The tableview scrolling is lagging and choppy.
However, if I **turn off the location access** to the application, everything is smooth and good!

I know usually the tableview lags because of improper handling of http calls or image download but if that is the case, same should happen if the location is turned off.

Can anyone please shed some light here?

Tested on iOS 9.1 and iOS 8.4

**Updated** Code for cellForRow....

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@“tableRow” forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];    

[dict setObjectOrDoNothing: [AppLoc currentLatitude] forKey:@“latitude”];

[dict setObjectOrDoNothing:[AppLoc currentLongitude]  forKey:@“longitude”];

[dict setObjectOrDoNothing:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]  forKey:@“content”];

[[AppManager serviceManager] postDataWithParams:dict];

return cell;

}
```

Where data is posted using AFNetworking and the lat, long methods essentially do the following:

```
[[AppLocationsManager sharedInstance] currentLocation].coordinate.latitude;

[[AppLocationsManager sharedInstance] currentLocation].coordinate.longitude;
```

Comment: post your cellforindexpath code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out the `locationManager.location` method is quite expensive specially when being used with high frequency (as was the case here). To resolve it. I cached the location from the location manager and pointed all the application components, even table cells to **use that cached location** instead of bugging the location manager every time.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should get location without cell, after that, call tableview.reloaddata()

p/s: I think you should share your code, so it 's easy to help